# How to automatically assign a client certificate in https RESTRequest communication on Android

Tags: android, rest, delphi

I'm using the TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse component stack for communication with the https REST API service. The Server authenticates the client by sending the request using the client certificate.

In my Android application, after calling the RestRequest.Execute (rmPost) method, a form appears asking for the selection of the client certificate. I would like to automatically assign a client certificate and avoid this additional question, but the RESTClient.OnNeedClientCertificate event is not fired.

I checked RESTLibrary, and I separately checked TNetHttpClient (the event OnNeedClientCertificate is also not fired), after several hours of reading blogs and performing dozen of tests, I am so frustrated as I have no idea how to solve the problem.

How can I avoid this additional question about choosing a client certificate and set the client certificate automatically?
Why is the TRESTClient.OnNeedClientCertificate event is not fired?

Thank you for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Inspecting the code in `TAndroidHTTPClient.DoGetClientCertificates` it looks like that feature is not supported for Android.

Comment: Comparing the TAndroidHTTPClient definition with TWinHTTPClient (Delphi 11.2), I see differences in the implementation of the DoGetClientCertificates method. I also see that in the TAndroidHTTPClient class definition there are several references related to client-side certificate handling (eq. FClientCertCache in TAndroidHTTPClient and TAndroidHTTPRequest , TX509TrustManager class). Unfortunately, in this regard, the documentation is limited to the sentence "Embarcadero does not currently have any additional information". In conclusion, is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Strange. In my installation TAndroidHTTPClient.DoGetClientCertificates ist merely empty. Which Delphi version are we talking about?

Comment: I wasn't precise, we're talking about Delphi 11.2, the procedure DoGetClientCertificates is marely empty.
*procedure TAndroidHTTPClient.DoGetClientCertificates(const ARequest: THTTPRequest; const ACertificateList: TList<TCertificate>);
begin
  inherited;
end;*

Comment: Which ends up with an empty list and OnNeedClientCertificate never been called.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this event is not handled on Android. But my problem still remains and I have no idea how to solve it. Is there any option to set client certificate programatically?